# Toggle class between list elements on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove and add a class between elements of a list, if I hit the `#swapThumb` button it should remove the `selected` class from the current element and then added to the next element.

Here's what I have

html

```
<ul id="product-thumbnails" class="thumbnails list-inline">
    <li class="vtmb vt-123 selected" style="">
        <a href="/uno"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="vtmb vt-456" style="">
        <a href="/dos"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="vtmb vt-789" style="display: none">
        <a href="/tres"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="vtmb vt-101" style="">
        <a href="/cuatro"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="vtmb vt-121" style="display: none">
        <a href="/cinco"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<button id="swapThumb">Next</button>
```

javascript

```
let thumbsNailsList = $('#product-thumbnails').find('li');
let swapButton = $('#swapThumb');

thumbsNailsList.each((index, item) => {

  let thumbsAvailable = $(item).attr('style');

  if (thumbsAvailable === '') {

    $(swapButton).on('click', () => {
      $(item).removeClass('selected');
      $(item).closest($(item)).next().addClass('selected');
    });
  }
});
```

First I'm checking if the `li` element has an empty `style` attribute (this is needed), if so, trigger the click validation.

The click should remove the `selected` class from the first element and then added to the next one and so on (it should match the empty `style` attribute). Once the `selected` class hits the last element of the `list` it should return the class to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will change the class of the element beneath it to selected and remove it from the current one, while keeping all the other classes. It will also loop back to the beginning element if `next` is clicked when on the last element. I've heard jQuery functions are more expensive that document functions and shouldn't be used for these kinds of things. Apply this to your problem and you should get the expected result

```js
let i = 0;
let thumbsNailsList = document.getElementById("product-thumbnails").children;
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() {
   var prevClasses = thumbsNailsList[i].className;
   thumbsNailsList[i].className = prevClasses.replace("selected", "");
   i = (i+1) % thumbsNailsList.length;
   thumbsNailsList[i].className = "selected";
   console.log(thumbsNailsList);
}
```

```html
<ul id="product-thumbnails">
  <li class='selected'></li>
  <li class=''></li>
  <li class=''></li>
  <li class=''></li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">Next</button>
```

Comment: Works fine, but it's applying the ***selected*** class to the next element with out checking if the ***style*** attribute is empty, I need to check this because there are other elements in the list which are hidden, and don't need the ***selected*** class...

Comment: @Rezpo ah ok i didnt know you were checking that aswell, i will update this when i have some time later today